# Solr what is the difference between query using q and df?

Tags: solr

I just did two things.

```
q -> iphone
df -> brand
```

and

```
q -> brand:iphone
```

Both returns same result.

First one looks for iphone string in brand field. Second one returns brand field whose value is phone.

What is the purpose of `df` field?

Comment: Both are same. if df is specified, term searched in df field. in case of q=brand:iphone value is searched in brand field not in default field. if neither df nor fieldname brand is specified term is searched in default field (again df) which is specified in solrconfig.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't any difference - but to show WHEN it would be different, you'll have to consider the case when you query a different field than the one provided in `df`.

```
q=model:foo&df=brand
```

This would lead to `foo` being matched against values in the field `model`, while `brand` is ignored. If the person writing the query however didn't specify a field, `brand` would be searched.

Most of the time you'd want to use the edismax or dismax query type (defType=edismax) to be able to create more suitable rules for which fields to query and the weight between the fields, and to handle how most people use a search field:

```
defType=edismax&q=foo&qf=brand^10 model
```

.. would search the fields brand and model for `foo`, and give a tenfold increase in score if the hit is in the brand field compared to the model field. Just `q=foo&qf=brand` would replicate your first query, and since edismax also supports parts of the lucene syntax, `q=brand:foo&qf=model` should also work.